# Can someone explain this Regex to me

Tags: c#, regex

I found this regex in working C# code. Can someone explain it to me please :

```
@"(?s)\{\{\s*" + templateTitle + @"(.*?)}}\r?\n?"
```

I tested it and it returns text like

```
{{   templateTitleValue     anything}}
```

What I don't understand is the two '}}' that are not escaped by \ like the two '}}'. And what is '(?s)' in the beginning.

Thanks

Comment: As a tool: http://regexr.com?36ohq

Comment: If this form is something you need, you could add that question along with it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, you don't need to escape the opening braces either. It's clear from context that they are not quantifiers (as in `X{1,3}` which would match `X`, `XX` or `XXX`). But it's good practice to escape them anyway (and to also escape the closing ones), just in case the regex changes into something where there *could* be some ambiguity.

`(?s)` means "allow the dot (`.`) to match *all* characters, including newlines". This is also known as the [`Singleline` or `DOTALL` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx).